# Producers with parameter injection?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, dependency-properties, cdi

How can I create a producer method that creates an object depending on a parameter?

My goal is to being able to inject a `CrudService` on different classes in my application, but to parametrize it with the class for which the service is used for (eg. `User.class`).

The following code does of course not work, but illustrates my intention.

```
@Produces
@JPAContainer(Class type) //something like this?
public JPAContainer getJPA() {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Produces
    @JPAContainerAnnot
    public JPAContainer getJPAContainer() {
       return JPAContainerFactory.make(type, em); //eg: class = User.class, Person.class
    }
}

@Stateless
public class CrudServiceUser() {
   @Inject
   @JPAContainer(type = User.class) //something like this parameter
   private JPAContainer container;
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,TYPE})
public @interface JPAContainer {

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can inject the `InjectionPoint` object in to your producer method.  the type attribute of your qualifier needs to be `@Nonbinding`.  From the `InjectionPoint` you can get reference to the annotations on the injection point, find your JPAContainer and read the values from it.